# How to validate an IP address with regular expression in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, regex, ip-address

How to validate an IP address in Objective-C?

Comment: I don't understand it. Why does it have to be regular expressions?

Comment: You might be better off with NSScanner, given there's no built-in regex library.

Comment: How can i do this with NSSCanner?

Comment: Although I side with the NSScanner, there IS and NSRegularExpression all fine and shiny in Obj-C (Actually in Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch). There are several stack-overflow questions and answers for matching IP addresses against regular expressions.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a category using the modern inet_pton which will return YES for a valid IPv4 or IPv6 string.

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    @implementation NSString (IPValidation)

    - (BOOL)isValidIPAddress
    {
        const char *utf8 = [self UTF8String];
        int success;

        struct in_addr dst;
        success = inet_pton(AF_INET, utf8, &dst);
        if (success != 1) {
            struct in6_addr dst6;
            success = inet_pton(AF_INET6, utf8, &dst6);
        }

        return success == 1;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: For future reference, the success == 1 ? TRUE : FALSE isn't needed. A simple success == 1 would work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative approach that might also help. Let's assume you have an `NSString*` that contains your IP address, called `ipAddressStr`, of the format *a.b.c.d*:

```
int ipQuads[4];
const char *ipAddress = [ipAddressStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

sscanf(ipAddress, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &ipQuads[0], &ipQuads[1], &ipQuads[2], &ipQuads[3]);

@try {
   for (int quad = 0; quad < 4; quad++) {
      if ((ipQuads[quad] < 0) || (ipQuads[quad] > 255)) {
         NSException *ipException = [NSException
            exceptionWithName:@"IPNotFormattedCorrectly"
            reason:@"IP range is invalid"
            userInfo:nil];
         @throw ipException;
      }
   }
}
@catch (NSException *exc) {
   NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [exc reason]);
}
```

You could modify the `if` conditional block to follow [RFC 1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) guidelines, if you need that level of validation.

Comment: Alex, did you mean to put a '&' before each ipQuad argument to sscanf?

Comment: I meant to, but I didn't. I will edit the answer after I add this comment. Also, I changed the type of `ipQuads` from `unsigned char` to `unsigned int`, so that the test has a chance to fail.

Comment: Since iOS 4 RegExps are available in iOS SDK: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html ... so, maybe if you want to mark this answer as deprecated "but useful for informative or educational purposes" will help :)

Comment: The comparison `ipQuads[quad] < 0` is always false because `ipQuads[quad]` is `unsigned`.

Answer (score 3):

Swift edition:

```
func isIPAddressValid(ip: String) -> Bool {
    guard let utf8Str = (ip as NSString).utf8String else {
        return false
    }

    let utf8:UnsafePointer<Int8> = UnsafePointer(utf8Str)
    var success: Int32

    var dst: in_addr = in_addr()
    success = inet_pton(AF_INET, utf8, &dst)
    if (success != 1) {
        var dst6: in6_addr? = in6_addr()
        success = inet_pton(AF_INET6, utf8, &dst6);
    }

    return success == 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A trick you can do is test the return of the inet_aton BSD call like this:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

- (BOOL)isIp:(NSString*)string{
    struct in_addr pin;
    int success = inet_aton([string UTF8String],&pin);
    if (success == 1) return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Be aware however that this validates the string if it contains a ip address in any format, it is not restricted to the dotted format.

Comment: FYI: `inet_aton` has been deprecated in favor of `inet_pton`, which handles IPv6.

Comment: Please if yo are returning a boolean from an if check just return the if check itself i.e.  `return success == 1`